# Get the text color of an AccessibilityNodeInfo

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the text color of an AccessibilityNodeInfo, like an android.widget.TextView

I tried ***getExtras()*** and ***getAvailableExtraData()***

I tried to use ***getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication().getDrawable()*** and ***getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication().getColor()*** but with no success

If someone has an idea.
Thank you.